# C++ : Two pointers (supposedly) to the same address. Changing contents of one of them don't change the contents of the other

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I am new in C++ and arduino and I not understanding what is going on.

The problem is :

I have the variables below :

```
char *_array;
char _data[2];
```

When I do : `_array = data;` And then I change the contents of _data, like `data[0] = 'C'`, `data[1] = 'D'`. The contents of _array don't change, and I need to do `_array = _data` again to apply the changes.

It seems that they don't point to the same address.

The code below is exemplifying this, the third print for me should be `"3CD"` instead of `"3AB"`, but it is not what happens.

Could you help me please? I don't understand. Thank you!

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
class Base {
    public:
        Base() {;};
        void setArray(char* array) {_array = array;}
        char *getArray() {return _array;}
    private:
        char *_array;
};

class A : public Base{
    public:
        A() : Base() {;};
        A(char data1, char data2)
        : Base()
        {
            setData(data1, data2);
            setArray(_data);
        }
        void setData(char data1, char data2)
        {
            _data[0] = data1;
            _data[1] = data2;
        }
        char *getData() {return _data;};

    private:
        char _data[2];
};

A a;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  a = A('A', 'B'); // This sets _data to "AB" and _array will point to _data
  Serial.write('1');
  Serial.write(a.getData()[0]);
  Serial.write(a.getData()[1]); // This will print "1AB" (as expected)

  a.setData('C', 'D'); // Here, _data changes to "CD" but _array no
  Serial.write('2');
  Serial.write(a.getData()[0]);
  Serial.write(a.getData()[1]); // This will print "2CD" (as expected)

  Serial.write('3');
  Serial.write(a.getArray()[0]);
  Serial.write(a.getArray()[1]); // This will print "3AB" (WHY?!?!?!)

  Serial.write('4');
  a.setArray(a.getData()); // If I call this function, _array changes to "CD"
  Serial.write(a.getArray()[0]);
  Serial.write(a.getArray()[1]); //This will print "4CD" (WHY I need to call setArray?)

  delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: I think your issue comes from the way you initialize your pointer. AFAIK, the line `_array = _data;` is an equivalent to `_array = &_data[0];` in this case.

Comment: If you have an empty function body you don't need the single semi-colon, just `{}` will work fine.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't prefix variables with an underscore - by convention, this is reserved for compiler use.  Use a trailing underscore instead - e.g. data_ instead of _data.

Comment: @Pete Actually, his usage of _ is perfectly fine. Simply saying "avoid identifiers starting with underscore" is generally good advice and very easy to remember. But, for completeness..: The standard says that any identifiers containing double underscore (__) or beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter (_A) as well as every globally declared identifier beginning with an underscore (_) belongs to "the implementation" (read compiler + linker). Since he's using a single underscore followed by lower case, and its not in global scope, it's fine.

Comment: @Pete As a strange counter-intuitive point of interest, all user-defined literal suffixes are reserved for the implementation *unless* they begin with an underscore. o.O

Comment: @Agentlien didn't realize it also had to have a capital letter.  interesting r.e. literal suffixes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = A('A', 'B'); // This sets _data to "AB" and _array will point to _data
```

In the above line, `A('A', 'B')` constructs a new A and establishes the internal `_array`. Then `a = ...` invokes the default assignment which just copies every member from source to destination. Now, `a._array` points to the char array of the temporary and that is how the invalid results come to be.

To avoid future errors,

- implement an assignment operator
- a copy constructor
- and also let the default constructor initialize _array.

Comment: ...or _delete_ the assignment operator, and use proper RAII to generate `a`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed this line to A a('A', 'B'); and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least write a copy constructor and an assignment operator for class A.  The default copy will copy the pointer and not re-assign it to the new location.

e.g.

```
A(A const& rhs) 
: Base(rhs)
{
    memcpy(_data, rhs._data, sizeof(_data));
    setArray(_data);
}


A& operator=(A const& rhs) 
{
    if (this != &rhs) {
        static_cast<Base&>(*this) = rhs;
        memcpy(_data, rhs._data, sizeof(_data));
        setArray(_data);
    }
    return *this;
}
```